# How do I map Docker Sonarr /tv folder to my QNAP host media folder?

Tags: docker

When I create a Docker Sonarr container it creates a couple of shared folders

e.g.

```
/tv -> /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Docker/container-station-data/lib/docker/volumes/6fed952ac3b86bca896db5396dd28ab397dd71fa329184427f301a1b34029613/_data
```

and my media is on my host `/share/Multimedia/TV Series`, but no matter what sort of softlink I create I can't get Docker Sonarr to see the contents of `/share/Multimedia/TV Series`. Could someone that has done this please advise me?

I should add that the QNAP runs the image in its Virtualisation Station so I don't start it with a CLI command.

Even if I map my media folder to this folder it doesn't work i.e. I can get a directory list of my media in the path below.

```
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Docker/container-station-data/lib/docker/volumes/6fed952ac3b86bca896db5396dd28ab397dd71fa329184427f301a1b34029613/_data/tv
```

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out.** When you create the container don't use the default **New Volume**! Instead use **Volume from host**, you may or may not need to set permissions. See the  [linuxserver/sonarr page](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/sonarr/) for more complete instructions on permissions.

[image]